# REST file download that takes 5 minutes to complete

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2

One of the API calls to my Web API 2 server from my Angular client dynamically generates an XLSX file via a ton of SQL queries and processing.  That can take up to five minutes to generate all the data and return it via a file download to the client.  Obviously that's bad because Chrome shows an error by then even though the page is still loading.

It feels like this is where I'd use a status code 202 to tell the client that it got the request, but I'm not sure after that how to actually send the file back to the client then.

The only thing I can think of is that the server spawns a background task that will write the file to a specific temp location, after it's been created, and then another API call will download that file if it exists and delete it from the temp location.

Is that what I do and then just have the client poll periodically for that file?  Pre-generating the file isn't an option as it has to have realtime data (at the point of request of course).

Comment: How about "your request to generate a mega report has been received. It will appear in the downloads area in about ten minutes' time", let them wander off, make a coffee, come back and download it. Also caches it so every man and his dog who wants the same report doesn't batter the server (if someone else requests the same report params, serve them the cached file)

Comment: How about emailing them the report when it's done, or emailing a note with a link to the done report?

Comment: Usually, you factor the generation into a own resource, let your original resource return code 202 in combination with the URI to the new resoure containing the actual download when it is being generated and in the meantime returning 304 when the process is still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It feels like this is where I'd use a status code 202 to tell the client that it got the request, but I'm not sure after that how to actually send the file back to the client then.

Usually a HTTP 202 comes with a location header and an indicator of where and when the resource will be available.
Also a possibility is to add a link to a status monitor, like described [here](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/).

To achieve this, you could generate an id for that process and use it in the location header url to point to the result.

The client then is able to get that resource when the resource *should* be ready. This means you would need some short-term persistence.